# First mouse click event on an item in a listbox doesn't trigger the function

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to do something like: when a user select an item on a listbox, then the function `listboxClicked` will be triggered. However, the first click often does not able to trigger the function. It only triggers the function when I click the same item or another item for the second time.

May I know what's wrong with my code? Thank you.

My Code:

```
    private void listbox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listbox.MouseClick += listboxClicked;
    }

    private void listboxClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listbox.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Listbox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Listbox listbox = (Listbox)sender;
    MessageBox.Show(listbox.SelectedItem.ToString());
}
```